# Log Requests from some Link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, request, response

How can i log requests that are going on some link?
I need to store requests Headers, Verb (Get or Post etc.), Request Data and Request Body. 
It's must be some separate application like Fiddler.

---

DESC: I have web application. It makes some search. I want to log data of search request using another application which can log any requests for some site (in my case for my web app). How to make it? I make research for solution but find many examples where user can create some Module or Filter which must be included in web application. This case for me is not allowed.

Comment: You can get data from Request property in your  controller action

Comment: @M.Azad, thanks for reply. This is clear for me, but i don't understand how to get request that goes not from my application. In ather words, i have 2 apps (they don't know about each other) First app makes some requests and second must detect what request makes first app and store request data in file or db.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of both sides, you can basically do whatever you want..

Maybe link to an action first that acts as a tracker:

```
public ActionResult Track()
{
    //get whatever data you want here
    //Request.Headers, Request.RequestType ect

    //track the data in a database or whatever
    SaveSomeData();

    //get the original url from a post variable, or querystring, where you put it
    var redirectUrl = Request["redirect"];

    return Redirect(redirectUrl);
 }
```

Then you would change your links for example a link to http://google.com, would change to
`http://mywebsite.com/mycontroller/track?url=http://google.com`

Another possible way would be to create a proxy, and monitor the data that goes through it.

Need a better idea of what you need though to help out more.

Comment: thanks for reply. Sorry, but i don't understand what you mean... Do i need to add `http://mywebsite.com/mycontroller/track?` this part of url before every request?